# PHP extract html tag and contents

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
    <p>paragraph 2</p>
    <p>paragraph 3</p>
    <p>paragraph 4</p>
    <ul>
        <li>item # 1</li>
        <li>item # 2</li>
        <li>item # 3</li>
        <li>item # 4</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">anchor 1</a>
    <a href="#">anchor 2</a>
    <a href="#">anchor 3</a>
    <a href="#">anchor 4</a>
    <div>div # 1</div>
    <div>div # 2</div>
    <div>div # 3</div>
    <div>div # 4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to extract a specified tag, lets say a div tag, and it's contents.

So far I have

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $file );
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $dom );
$paragraphs = $xpath->query("/html/body//p");

for( $i = 0; $i < $paragraphs->length; $i++ )
{
     # echo the tag and it's contents
}
```

I tried using `nodeValue` or `textContent` but they just print the content of the tag and not the tags plus their content.

This is my first time using the DOM parser in PHP. I know that the use of regexes to parse HTML/XML is protested against so I am using the DOM parser. Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for PHP version 5.3.6+. Just pass the node to the DOMDocument::saveHTML function.

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $paragraphs->length; $i++ )
{
     echo $dom->saveHTML($paragraph->item($i));
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: simple and small. just what I needed

Comment: `foreach($paragraphs as $pargraph) {` is also simpler.

Comment: why php 5.3.6+ only?